# Cross-domain HTML source extraction using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, jsonp, same-origin-policy

Say I am in domain  `abc.com`. I want to be able to get the HTML source of a page on `xyz.com` and then parse it using JavaScript. I know there is restriction of ***same origin policy***, and I tried `CORS`which the server at `xyz.com` does not support. Is it possible to achieve this using `JSONP`? Can you guys tell me with some code snippets how?

Comment: for using jsonp, server should bind the response with a function. But in your need, it is not possible. Better think serverside httpget()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use `JSONP` or `CORS`, the server must be able to provide support for it. So if you're not in control of `xyz.com`, and it doesn't provide this already, you can't do it on the client side. Instead, you have to process it on the server side.

Comment: I am in no control of xyz.com. For CORS, I knew the server at xyz.com should be able to provide the support for it. So it is the same for JSONP as well. So then I have no other option than server side. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

for using jsonp, server should bind the response with a function. But in your need, it is not possible. Better think serverside HttpGet() function

Comment: So you mean it is because the server at xyz.com which does not provide support for this.